# Sorting Algorithm for XML attribute mutual value pairs

Tags: java, xml, powershell, sorting, graph-algorithm

### Premise:

I am trying to find or rather come up with an algorithm to parse several XML files and extract a launch sequence saved in `FROM=XX`, and `TO=YY` node attributes.

- There are hundreds of records and can be split into pairs
- Each would have ***`FROM`*** and ***`TO`*** value
- Each pair's ***`TO`*** value is an indicator that there is a new pair having it as a ***`FROM`*** value
- so the pairs would chain and create continuous set of ***`FROM-TO`*** values.

The tricky part is, that the pairing can split, branch, into multiple ones and join at certain point.

### The XML:

```
<FLOW>
    <TASK FROM ="B" TO ="C"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="E1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="F1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A1" TO ="A2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A2" TO ="A3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A3" TO ="C"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="D1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D2" TO ="D3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D1" TO ="D2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E1" TO ="E2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="Start" TO ="B"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E2" TO ="E3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F1" TO ="F2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F2" TO ="F3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F3" TO ="G"/>
    <TASK FROM ="Start" TO ="A1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="G" TO ="Finish"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E3" TO ="G"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D3" TO ="G"/>
</FLOW>
```

#### I can help to visualise that like the following diagram:

```
    Start
  /        \  
 [A1]       |
  |         |
 [A2]      [B]
  |         |
 [A3]       |
   \       /
      [C]
   /   |    \ 
[D1]  [E1]  [F1]      
 |     |     |
[D2]  [E2]  [F2]
 |     |     |
[D3]  [E3]  [F3]
 \     |    /
      [G]
       |
     Finish
```

### Desired output:

> Start, A1, A2, A3, B, C, D1, D2, D3, E1, E2, E3, F1, F2, F3, G, Finish

### Problem:

I have this code running but I can't get it to work with correct order and to overcome the splits.

```
<# 
    INIT Values, starting pair is always considered as combination of tasks where FROM is 'Start'
    All task are loaded in pairs, and the sequence begining is assembled.
#>

$Counter = [int]1
$Pairs = $File.SelectNodes('/FLOW/TASK[@FROM="Start"]')
$Tasks = $File.SelectNodes("/FLOW/TASK")

$Sequence = @()
ForEach ($Pair in $Pairs) {
    $Sequence += $Pair.TOTASK
}

<#
    Scan the tasks and find the matching pair for initial task pair, save it to the output array. 
#>

Do {
    ForEach ($Task in $Tasks) {
        ## Main loop counter, on matching pairs
        If ($Pairs.FROM -eq $Task.FROM) {
               $Counter++ 
        }
        ## Find current pair's TO in task and flag it as next pair 
        If ($Pairs.TO -eq $Task.FROM) {
            $NextTask = $Task.FROM
            $NextPairs = $File.SelectNodes("/FLOW/TASK[@FROM='$NextTask']")
            $Sequence += $Task.TO
        }
    }

    ## Set new pair to be evaluated
    $Pairs = $NextPairs
} 
While ($Counter -le $Tasks.Count)
```

Comment: What decides whether "A1, A2, A3" or "B" comes first in the output? Can the output be also [Start, A1, B, A2, A3, C, ...]?

Comment: Yes, in fact that are parallel tasks, it can go like that. The rule is that A3 and B has to be before C. The sorting of desired output was merely 'logical' sequence, as if I would first finish one branch, then join another. Although, the loops will interpret that whatever comes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted it took me a while to come up with an optimized solution for you. Here goes:

### Solution (Graphs!)

Ok, why don't you approach this the same way you would in an OOP language:

```
# Use a hashtable for O(1) lookup for a node by name
$Script:NodeTracker = @{}
class TaskNode {
    #==PROPS==================================================|
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$then = @()
    [String] $Val
    [Bool]$Visited = $false
    [Collections.ArrayList]$Parent = @()
    #==CONSTRUCTORS===========================================|
    TaskNode([String]$Val) {$this.constructor($Val, $null)}
    TaskNode([String]$Val, [TaskNode]$Parent) {$this.constructor($Val, $Parent)}
    hidden constructor([String]$Val, [TaskNode]$Parent) {
        $This.Val = $Val
        if ($Parent) {$This.Parents.Add($Parent)}
        $Script:NodeTracker.$Val = $This
    }

    #==METHODS================================================|
    [TaskNode] To([String]$Val) {
        $Node = $Script:NodeTracker.$Val

        # If node doesn't exist, create and track
        if (!$Node) {$Node = New-Object TaskNode $Val}
        $This.then.Add($Node)
        $Node.Parent.Add($This)
        return $Node
    }
    [String] ToString() {return "$($this.val)-$(if($this.Visited){'✓'}else{'✘'})"}
    static [String] ReverseModdedBFS([Collections.Queue]$Queue) {
        $Output = ""
        [Collections.Queue]$NextQueue = @()
        do {
            while ($Queue.Count) {
                $Root = $Queue.Dequeue()
                # Write-Host "Root: $Root | Queue: [$Queue] | Next-Queue [$NextQueue] | Non-Visited [$($Root.then | {!$_.Visited})]"
                if ($Root.Visited) {continue}
                if ($Root.Then.Count -gt 1 -and ($Root.then | {!$_.Visited})) {$NextQueue.Enqueue($Root);continue}
                $Root.Visited = $true
                $Output += ','+$Root.Val
                $Root.Parent | % {
                    # Write-Host "    Enqueuing $_"
                    $Queue.Enqueue($_)
                }
            }
            If ($Queue.Count -eq 1 -and !$Queue.Peek().Parent.count) {break}
            $Queue = $NextQueue
            $NextQueue = @()
        } while($Queue.Count)
        $Out = $Output.Substring(1).split(',')
        [Array]::Reverse($Out)
        return $Out -join ','
    }
    #==STATICS=================================================|
    static [TaskNode] Fetch([String]$Val) {
        $Node = $Script:NodeTracker.$Val
        # If node doesn't exist, create and track
        if (!$Node) {return (New-Object TaskNode $Val)}
        return $Node
    }
    static [TaskNode[]] GetAll() {
        return @($Script:NodeTracker.Values)
    }
    static [TaskNode] GetStart() {
        $Nodes = [TaskNode]::GetAll() | {$_.Parent.count -eq 0}
        if ($Nodes.Count -gt 1) {throw 'There is more than one starting node!'}
        if (!$Nodes.Count) {throw 'There is no starting node!'}
        return @($Nodes)[0]
    }
    static [TaskNode[]] GetEnds() {
        $Nodes = [TaskNode]::GetAll() | {$_.Then.count -eq 0}
        if (!$Nodes.Count) {throw 'There is no ending node!'}
        return @($Nodes)
    }
}

function Parse-Edge($From, $To) {
    # Use the safe static accessor so that it will fetch the singleton instance of the node, or create and return one!
    [TaskNode]::Fetch($From).To($To)
}

function XML-Main([xml]$XML) {
    @($XML.Flow.Task) | % {Parse-Edge $_.From $_.To}
    [TaskNode]::ReverseModdedBFS([TaskNode]::GetEnds())
}
```

### Test for proof!

I tested it like the following:

```
#Create or Find root node 'O'
$Root = [TaskNode]::Fetch('O')

# Set up Chains! Please draw to test
$root.To('A').To('B').To('C').To('H').To('Z').To('M')
$Root.To('D').To('E').To('C').To('H').To('I').To('M')
$Root.To('F').To('G').To('C').To('H').To('J').To('M')
[TaskNode]::Fetch('C').To('K').To('L').To('M')

# Run BFS!
[TaskNode]::ReverseModdedBFS([TaskNode]::GetEnds())
```

### Output of Test

```
Root: M-✘ | Queue: [] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing Z-✘
    Enqueuing I-✘
    Enqueuing J-✘
    Enqueuing L-✘
Root: Z-✘ | Queue: [I-✘ J-✘ L-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing H-✘
Root: I-✘ | Queue: [J-✘ L-✘ H-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing H-✘
Root: J-✘ | Queue: [L-✘ H-✘ H-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing H-✘
Root: L-✘ | Queue: [H-✘ H-✘ H-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing K-✘
Root: H-✘ | Queue: [H-✘ H-✘ K-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing C-✘
    Enqueuing C-✘
    Enqueuing C-✘
Root: H-✓ | Queue: [H-✓ K-✘ C-✘ C-✘ C-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: H-✓ | Queue: [K-✘ C-✘ C-✘ C-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: K-✘ | Queue: [C-✘ C-✘ C-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing C-✘
Root: C-✘ | Queue: [C-✘ C-✘ C-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing B-✘
    Enqueuing E-✘
    Enqueuing G-✘
Root: C-✓ | Queue: [C-✓ C-✓ B-✘ E-✘ G-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: C-✓ | Queue: [C-✓ B-✘ E-✘ G-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: C-✓ | Queue: [B-✘ E-✘ G-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: B-✘ | Queue: [E-✘ G-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing A-✘
Root: E-✘ | Queue: [G-✘ A-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing D-✘
Root: G-✘ | Queue: [A-✘ D-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing F-✘
Root: A-✘ | Queue: [D-✘ F-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing O-✘
Root: D-✘ | Queue: [F-✘ O-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing O-✘
Root: F-✘ | Queue: [O-✘ O-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
    Enqueuing O-✘
Root: O-✘ | Queue: [O-✘ O-✘] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: O-✓ | Queue: [O-✓] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
Root: O-✓ | Queue: [] | Next-Queue [] | Non-Visited []
O,F,D,A,G,E,B,C,K,H,L,J,I,Z,M
```

---

## Explanation, and Algo

We use a [***graph***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_graph) to plot all edges to each other using some nifty OOP tricks. Then we traverse the graph in reverse from all sink nodes (*ie. nodes that have **no children***). We keep doing [***BFS***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) till we hit a node that:

- Has more than 1 child
- **AND**, has more than 0 non-visited descendants
- If so, add that for the next round of BFS!

Repeat this till your current and future queues are empty, in which case, your output is now complete. Now:

- Split by comma
- Reverse array (*since we did a reverse traversal*)
- Print output!

Comment: That looks interesting, BFS is definitely the type of sorting I was looking for. I will try that out and see how that behaves and I will play with the joining branches at certain point.

Comment: Sures thing! I made the API pretty intuitive, so you can chain the `.To('<Value>')`'s to create chains of whatever sizes. As they all internally use the singleton pattern. It should also work for N random forks and varying depths.

Comment: @JimB if this worked for you can you please upvote and mark as Answer? A lot of time was put into creating this solution

Comment: Sure, I do that, I am trying to adapt this solution to the specifics of my case, but I think I am on a good way! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This script will print out what you want. It's self-contained so you can copy it all and run it. There's room for improvement!

One thing: This assumes **one split at a time**, like in your sample. If this scenario is possible, more logic is required:

```
 |     |       |
 |     |       |
[D3]  [E3]   [F3]
 \     | \    /
  \    | [H] /              - spit from C is not resolved, F1, F2 and F3 not handled
   \   | /  /  
      [G]
       |
     Finish
```

---

```
$script:xml = [xml] @"
<FLOW>
    <TASK FROM ="B" TO ="C"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="E1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="F1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A1" TO ="A2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A2" TO ="A3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="A3" TO ="C"/>
    <TASK FROM ="C" TO ="D1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D2" TO ="D3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D1" TO ="D2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E1" TO ="E2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="Start" TO ="B"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E2" TO ="E3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F1" TO ="F2"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F2" TO ="F3"/>
    <TASK FROM ="F3" TO ="G"/>
    <TASK FROM ="Start" TO ="A1"/>
    <TASK FROM ="G" TO ="Finish"/>
    <TASK FROM ="E3" TO ="G"/>
    <TASK FROM ="D3" TO ="G"/>
</FLOW>
"@

Function GetNextNode {
    param($node)

    $nextNode = $xml.FLOW.TASK |
                    Where-Object {$_.FROM -eq $node.TO} |
                    Sort-Object TO
    return $nextNode

}

Function GetPrevNode {
    param($node)

    $nextNode = $xml.FLOW.TASK |
                    Where-Object {$_.TO -eq $node.FROM} |
                    Sort-Object TO
    return $nextNode

}

$startNode   = $xml.FLOW.TASK | Where-Object {$_.FROM -eq "Start"} | Sort-Object TO

do{
    # deal with the start node as it's a special case
    if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($startNode)){

        # start node is the start of the chain
        [array]$mainChain = $startNode[0]

        # if you have two or more nodes, store them for now. They will be referenced later
        if($startNode.Count -gt 1){
            [array]$splitterNode  = $startNode
        }

        # take the first start node and find out which node it leads to
        [array]$nextNode = GetNextNode -node $startNode[0]

        # add one of the nodes. set $oldNode for next iteration
        [array]$mainChain += $nextNode[0]
        [array]$oldNode  = $nextNode[0]

        # this is only for the first node, don't run through again
        $startNode = $null
        continue

    }


    # get the next node AND previus nodes for that next node
    [array]$nextNode   = GetNextNode -node $oldNode[0]
    [array]$prevNode   = GetPrevNode -node $nextNode[0]

    if($prevNode.Count -ne 1){

        # if there are multiple previous nodes, go back and deal with them
        # to do this, go back to the $splitterNode
        if(-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($splitterNode)){

            # exclude anything already added
            [array]$remainingNodes = $splitterNode | Where-Object {$_ -notin $mainChain}

            # if that leaves only one node, others have been dealt with
            # there is no longer a split
            if($remainingNodes.Count -eq 1){               
                $splitterNode = $null
            }

            [array]$oldNode = $remainingNodes[0]
            $mainChain += $remainingNodes[0]
            continue

        }else{

            # if there is no $splitterNode, all previous nodes should already be in the chain
            # check
            foreach($node in $prevNode){
                if($node -notin $mainChain){
                    Write-Host "Broken chain"
                    Exit
                }
            }

        }
    }

    # if this node is a splitter, set it so it can be referenced later
    if($nextNode.Count -gt 1){
        $splitterNode = $nextNode
    }

    # add this node to the chain. 
    [array]$mainChain += $nextNode[0]
    [array]$oldNode = $nextNode[0]

}while($oldNode.To -ne "Finish")

($mainChain.FROM | Select-Object -Unique) + "Finish" | Out-Host
```

Comment: Thank you, this is easier for me to read. I will examine the options and how to treat all possibilities. I.e. the ones you suggested, or when the Start chains and splits later on n-th node, rather then on the beginning etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seem to be subject to [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) and having the greatest and least elements. What you need is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

One way to do it (in C++) is below. This is depth-first-search, compared to breadth-first-search in the accepted answer. This might be easier to read.

```
struct Node
{
    Node(string name)
    {
        this->name = name;
        visited = false;
    }
    string name;
    deque<Node*> next;
    bool visited;
};

void visit(Node* node, deque<Node*>& sorted_nodes)
{
    if (node->visited)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (auto n : node->next)
    {
        visit(n, sorted_nodes);
    }
    node->visited = true;
    sorted_nodes.push_front(node);
}

deque<Node*> serialize_dag(Node* root)
{
    deque<Node*> sorted_nodes;    
    visit(root, sorted_nodes);
    return sorted_nodes;
}
```